# What is the issue with the workbook template

Tags: javascript, dashboard, azure-monitor-workbooks

I tried to deploy the workbook nothing happens after i click apply, what is the issue with this workbook

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "resourcegroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "workspace": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "workspaceapiversion": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "[parameters('workspaceapiversion')]",
            "name": "[parameters('workspace')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "id": "[Concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourcegroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspace'))]",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-11-01-preview",
                    "name": "WVD Information",
                    "type": "views",
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "id": "[Concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourcegroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspace'),'/views/WVD Information')]",
                    "dependson": [
                        "[Concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourcegroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspace'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "Id": "WVD Information",
                        "Name": "WVD Information",
                        "Author": null,
                        "Source": "Local",
                        "Version": 2,
                        "Dashboard": [
                            {
                                "Id": "TwoNumberTileListBuilderBlade",
                                "Type": "Blade",
                                "Version": 0,
                                "Configuration": {
                                    "General": {
                                        "title": "Hosts and Hostpools",
                                        "newGroup": false,
                                        "icon": "",
                                        "useIcon": false
                                    },
                                    "Tile": {
                                        "Legend": "HostPools",
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | summarize HostPools=dcount(Details_SessionHostPoolName_s)"
                                    },
                                    "SecondTile": {
                                        "Legend": "Total Hosts",
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | summarize Hosts=dcount(Details_SessionHostName_s)"
                                    },
                                    "List": {
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | summarize Sessions=dcount(UserName_s) by Hosts=Details_SessionHostPoolName_s",
                                        "HideGraph": false,
                                        "enableSparklines": false,
                                        "ColumnsTitle": {
                                            "Name": "HostPools",
                                            "Value": "Sessions"
                                        },
                                        "Color": "#0072c6",
                                        "thresholds": {
                                            "isEnabled": false,
                                            "values": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Normal",
                                                    "threshold": "Default",
                                                    "color": "#009e49",
                                                    "isDefault": true
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Warning",
                                                    "threshold": "60",
                                                    "color": "#fcd116",
                                                    "isDefault": false
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Error",
                                                    "threshold": "90",
                                                    "color": "#ba141a",
                                                    "isDefault": false
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "NameDSVSeparator": "",
                                        "NavigationQuery": "search {selected item} | sort by TimeGenerated desc",
                                        "NavigationSelect": {
                                            "NavigationQuery": "search {selected item} | sort by TimeGenerated desc"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "Blade": {
                                        "NavigationSelect": {}
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Id": "TwoNumberTileListBuilderBlade",
                                "Type": "Blade",
                                "Version": 0,
                                "Configuration": {
                                    "General": {
                                        "title": "Hosts and Sessions",
                                        "newGroup": false,
                                        "icon": "",
                                        "useIcon": false
                                    },
                                    "Tile": {
                                        "Legend": "Hosts",
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | summarize Hosts=dcount(Details_SessionHostName_s)"
                                    },
                                    "SecondTile": {
                                        "Legend": "Unique Users",
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | summarize Sessions=dcount(UserName_s)"
                                    },
                                    "List": {
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | summarize Sessions=dcount(UserName_s) by Hosts=Details_SessionHostName_s",
                                        "HideGraph": false,
                                        "enableSparklines": false,
                                        "ColumnsTitle": {
                                            "Name": "HostName",
                                            "Value": "Sessions"
                                        },
                                        "Color": "#0072c6",
                                        "thresholds": {
                                            "isEnabled": false,
                                            "values": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Normal",
                                                    "threshold": "Default",
                                                    "color": "#009e49",
                                                    "isDefault": true
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Warning",
                                                    "threshold": "60",
                                                    "color": "#fcd116",
                                                    "isDefault": false
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Error",
                                                    "threshold": "90",
                                                    "color": "#ba141a",
                                                    "isDefault": false
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "NameDSVSeparator": "",
                                        "NavigationQuery": "search {selected item} | sort by TimeGenerated desc",
                                        "NavigationSelect": {
                                            "NavigationQuery": "search {selected item} | sort by TimeGenerated desc"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "Blade": {
                                        "NavigationSelect": {}
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "Id": "NumberTileListBuilderBlade",
                                "Type": "Blade",
                                "Version": 0,
                                "Configuration": {
                                    "General": {
                                        "title": "Session Errors",
                                        "newGroup": false,
                                        "icon": "",
                                        "useIcon": false
                                    },
                                    "Tile": {
                                        "Legend": "Count of Errors",
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | where (Error_Message_s contains \"User Profile Disk setup failed for\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"There are currently no resources available to connect to\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"PreAuthLogonFailed\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"GatewayProtocolError\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"User Profile Disk setup failed at stage\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"Orchestration request failed Exception\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"failed\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"fail\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"One or more errors occurred\") | summarize count(Error_Message_s)",
                                        "NavigationSelect": {}
                                    },
                                    "List": {
                                        "Query": "WVD_CL | where (Error_Message_s contains \"User Profile Disk setup failed for\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"There are currently no resources available to connect to\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"PreAuthLogonFailed\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"GatewayProtocolError\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"User Profile Disk setup failed at stage\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"Orchestration request failed Exception\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"failed\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"fail\") or (Error_Message_s contains \"One or more errors occurred\") | project UserName=UserName_s, Error=Error_Message_s, Time=TimeGenerated | top 10 by UserName desc ",
                                        "HideGraph": false,
                                        "enableSparklines": false,
                                        "ColumnsTitle": {
                                            "Name": "Computer",
                                            "Value": "Log Time"
                                        },
                                        "Color": "#0072c6",
                                        "thresholds": {
                                            "isEnabled": false,
                                            "values": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Normal",
                                                    "threshold": "Default",
                                                    "color": "#009e49",
                                                    "isDefault": true
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Warning",
                                                    "threshold": "60",
                                                    "color": "#fcd116",
                                                    "isDefault": false
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "Error",
                                                    "threshold": "90",
                                                    "color": "#ba141a",
                                                    "isDefault": false
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "NameDSVSeparator": "",
                                        "NavigationQuery": "search {selected item} | sort by TimeGenerated desc",
                                        "NavigationSelect": {
                                            "NavigationQuery": "search {selected item} | sort by TimeGenerated desc"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "Filters": [],
                        "OverviewTile": {
                            "Id": "LineChartCalloutBuilderTile",
                            "Type": "OverviewTile",
                            "Version": 2,
                            "Configuration": {
                                "LineChart": {
                                    "Query": "WVD_CL | summarize Sessions= count(UserName_s) by UserName_s, bin(TimeGenerated, 24h)",
                                    "Callout": {
                                        "Title": "Sessions by HostPool",
                                        "Series": "",
                                        "Operation": "Count"
                                    },
                                    "yAxis": {
                                        "isLogarithmic": false,
                                        "units": {
                                            "baseUnitType": "",
                                            "baseUnit": "",
                                            "displayUnit": ""
                                        },
                                        "customLabel": ""
                                    }
                                },
                                "Advanced": {
                                    "DataFlowVerification": {
                                        "Enabled": false,
                                        "Query": "search * | limit 1 | project TimeGenerated",
                                        "Message": ""
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

That content is not an Azure Workbook.

```
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
```

The schema says this JSON content is an ARM deployment template, and based on the content inside it is for solution based view designer views (which are mostly deprecated, though you may be able to deploy them via a template?)  If you're trying to use this inside the workbook advanced mode, it is JSON, so it will pass *that* part of the validation, but there isn't any workbook content inside, so when parsed by workbooks, it will lead to an empty workbook.

you could *convert* that to a workbook *manually* though, as there are various logs queries inside you could run from workbooks:

```
WVD_CL | summarize HostPools=dcount(Details_SessionHostPoolName_s)
```

inside the workbook gallery for log analytics workspaces, there's a section of templates called "View Designer Guides" that has information on how to manually convert various view designer items into their closest workbook equivalents.

To deploy this as a template from inside the azure portal, in the top search box type `deploy a custom template`, and choose that item from the services list.

in the ui it opens, click the "build your own template in the editor" and paste the content from above, and press save.

it will parse the template deployment and show you all the things you need to fill in to deploy this item to a workspace.